# Div element scrolling instead of expanding on overflow:auto

Tags: html, css, angularjs, overflow

I an angularJS application with the following segment of HTML code:

```
<div class="rightNavBarQuiz">

    <div ng-show="showNoteList">

        <div id="noteBar" data-ng-click="viewNote(note); notePreview=!notePreview" ng-repeat="note in notesList" ng-swipe-left="checked = true">
            <div id="noteListScreenshot"></div>
            <div id="noteListTitle">{{note.moduleName}}: {{note.videoName}}</div>
            <div id="noteListStats">Duration: {{note.videoDuration}} Seconds</div>
            <div id="noteText" ng-show="notePreview">{{noteText}}</div>
            <div id="ViewButton"></div>

        <div id="deleteNoteButton" ng-show="checked" ng-swipe-right="checked = false" data-ng-click="deleteNote(note.noteId)">Delete?</div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Basically, the text in the 'noteText' div increases and expands the div when the parent div 'noteBar' is clicked. I am having an issue making 'noteBar' expand with the 'noteText' div. Over:auto just seems to make the parent div 'noteBar' scrollable instead of expanding its height.

Below is the CSS for 'notetext'and its containers 'rightNavBarQuiz', 'showNoteList' and 'noteBar':

```
.rightNavBarQuiz{
border-style:solid;
    height: 99%;
    width: 71%;
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#noteBar{
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top:1px dotted grey;
    border-bottom:1px dotted grey;
    margin-top:4px;
}

#noteText{
    color: grey;
    position: absolute;
    height:auto;
    width:170px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 113px;
    float:left;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#noteText{
    ...
    overflow:visible;
}
```

(instead of `overflow: auto`)

Comment: The exact same thing still happens, the div scrolls instead of expanding

Comment: That's very strange...I'm not sure about that one. Something about your JS configuration is disallowing it for some reason, I think. Try doing `overflow:visible` on `#noteBar` as well as `#noteText`.